# IF Statement with Columns?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I am trying to type a formula that will perform the IF statement results. I am unable to make it work on Google Sheets.

I have columns from A to EQ. I want to have the formula focus on the B2.

- If B2 says "D" for column D and it is less than Z, then the statement is true.
- If B2 says "AC" for column AC and it is greater than Z, then the statement is false.

Formulas I tried to do:
    =IF(B2<"Z","DO THIS","IF NOT, DO THIS THEN")

The link to the sheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19HfSzHK_xA6F2Ysxc7B_JD9stqCCxxqNHV3nRAEcUzk/edit?usp=sharing

Focus on two tabs. Budget tab: Range: A4:B11, Cells F6, F7, S6, S7, AE6 and AE7 Denominacion tab: Issue is in column B starting at B4 and down.

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking here. Are you saying that B2 tells you which column to find the value that should be checked?

Comment: Yes, Alan. B2 will tell me the column to check. Basically, I want the formula to work for ANY column regardless if it says Column A, Column DE or Column ZZZZZ... you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions for this example:

> B2 contains the *column* you want
>   A4 contains the *row* you want

What you want to do is build your location string first, then check the location. Wrap the whole thing up with `IFERROR` if you want to have the cell blank rather than display an error if one of the cells is blank.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B2, A4)), "")
```

UPDATE: Correct me if I am wrong, but based on the spreadsheet you have shared it looks like you are trying to calculate a cell location (which I have answered above) and then manually calculate what the location is of the cell one cell to the right. Do not do this. You should use the function "OFFSET" which will do it for you.

I have tested in your spreadsheet and this formula works:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Budget!"&$B$2&A4))), "", OFFSET(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Budget!"&$B$2&A4)),0,1) )
```

CONCATENATE joins the text values of each cell together
INDIRECT tells the spreadsheet that this string is a cell reference
OFFSET redirects the formula to a cell [numbers of rows], [number of columns] aways from the starting point i.e. one column to the right (left would be a negative number)

Comment: I would want to keep the H2 value dynamic. H2 would say "Savings" and I want the formula to pull the value and insert it where the formula lies in the cell.

Comment: Then the first formula I have given `=IFERROR(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B2, A4)), "")` is the answer. The rest of the answer is optional scenarios exploring other capabilities of the same technique.

Comment: I tried inserting your formula into my formula and it is not working still. I just made the sheet editable.

`=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Budget!"&$B$2&A4)),"",IFERROR(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B2, A4)), "")<"Z",CHAR(CODE(LEFT($B$2,2))+1),LEFT($B$2,2))&A4))`

Comment: Alan! Thank you! This is what I am looking for! I knew it was not Char(Code thingy... it was the OFFSET I was looking for! -___- 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use indirect which looks ups a ranges contents where the range is a string supplied

```
=IF(INDIRECT(B2 & ROW()) < INDIRECT("Z" & ROW()),
    "DO THIS",
    "IF NOT, DO THIS THEN")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Robin. It does not work. I will paste the formula that worked well in Excel but not so much in Google Sheets.

=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Budget!"&$B$2&A4)),"",INDIRECT("Budget‌​!"&IF(RIGHT($B$2,1)<‌​"Z",CHAR(CODE(LEFT($‌​B$2,1))+1),LEFT($B$2‌​,1))&A4)) 

A4 is the row number value that will pull the value from (Example: B2 would say C, A4 would say 10 then the cell will be C10 and the value in C10 would be "Savings".

I wish I can upload a sample sheet here.

Comment: Make a (clean) sheet public in google docs and then add the link to your question.

Comment: Okay, here it is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19HfSzHK_xA6F2Ysxc7B_JD9stqCCxxqNHV3nRAEcUzk/edit?usp=sharing

Focus on two tabs. 
Budget tab: Range: A4:B11, Cells F6, F7, S6, S7, AE6 and AE7
Denominacion tab: Issue is in column B starting at B4 and down.